# How to get active record sessions work in Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into a CookieOverflow error, so I want to switch to database sessions.

In config/environment.rb:

```
Uncommented: config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
Changed:  :secret for config.action_controller.session
```

In application.rb:

```
Uncommented: protect_from_forgery :secret => 'ac44a970c0047c1b049c1967986af674'
```

I ran some 'rake ...' commands it told me to, and it created this database table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`session_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`data` text,
`created_at` datetime default NULL,
`updated_at` datetime default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
KEY `index_sessions_on_session_id` (`session_id`),
KEY `index_sessions_on_updated_at` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now, that seems all good and done. *BUT* it never writes any sessions to the database. Logins still work though. What else do I have to do to make this work? How is this even working if it's using active record sessions and not writing any session data to the database...?

Is there an easy way to step through/troubleshoot this?

Comment: You definitely don't have any rows in your sessions table?

Comment: SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE 1
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). Query took 0.00002 sec)

Comment: Somebody on the Rails forum noted that I should restart the server after editing environment.rb, so trying to find out how I get RailsPlayground to do that for me now...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have cookie sessions enabled in development.rb (or whatever environment you're running this in).  After that, please post your sessions controller.